# How to use several expressions in MySQL IF clause

Tags: mysql

`mysql IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)`

I want to use two sentences to expr2 or expr3. Is it possible? Or is there another way?

```
select @a:=0, @b:=0, @c:=0 ,if(1>0 , @a:=1 and @b:=2, @b:=9 and @c:=8) as if_r,
       @a,@b,@c 
from dual
```

It seems to work and outputs:

```
+-------+-------+-------+------+------+------+------+
| @a:=0 | @b:=0 | @c:=0 | if_r | @a   | @b   | @c   |
+-------+-------+-------+------+------+------+------+
|     0 |     0 |     0 |    1 | 1    | 2    | 0    |
+-------+-------+-------+------+------+------+------+
```

But

```
select @a:=0, @b:=0, @c:=0 ,if(1>2 , @a:=1 and @b:=2, @b:=9 and @c:=8) as if_r,
       @a,@b,@c 
from dual
```

Gives

```
+-------+-------+-------+------+------+------+------+
| @a:=0 | @b:=0 | @c:=0 | if_r | @a   | @b   | @c   |
+-------+-------+-------+------+------+------+------+
|     0 |     0 |     0 |    1 | 0    | 1    | 8    |
+-------+-------+-------+------+------+------+------+
```

I want to double execute at on string like this

```
+-------+-------+-------+------+------+------+------+
| @a:=0 | @b:=0 | @c:=0 | if_r | @a   | @b   | @c   |
+-------+-------+-------+------+------+------+------+
|     0 |     0 |     0 |    1 | 0    | 9    | 8    |
+-------+-------+-------+------+------+------+------+
```

How to query for that?

Comment: mysql doesn't give you any guarantees about the order your select fields are parsed, so you can't use variables like that.

Comment: _I want to double execute at on string like this_ -- What do you mean by that?